# How can I get a image with gradient without blended layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-graphics

In my UITableViewCell there is a background UIImageView. If I use the raw image download from server there is no blended layer showed on that ImageView. But if I add gradient to the image downloaded (some images contain lots of white space which make it hard to see the front label, so I have to make the image darker), blended layer showed. How can I add gradient to the image while avoiding blended layer?

[image]
[image]

The code used to generate image with gradient is showed below:

```
- (UIImage *)gs_imageWithDownsideShadow {
    return [self gs_imageWithShadow:@[[UIColor gs_colorWithSameRGB:0 alpha:0.3], [UIColor gs_colorWithSameRGB:0 alpha:0.5]]];
}

- (UIImage *)gs_imageWithShadow:(NSArray *)colors
{
    CGSize size = self.size;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);

    CGFloat locations[] = {0.0, 1.0};
    NSMutableArray *colorRefs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIColor *color in colors) {
        [colorRefs addObject:(__bridge id)color.CGColor];
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(baseSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colorRefs, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: You can add a UIView above image and under your label, set it color to black or grey and alpha to 0.3 for example

Comment: @DianaProdan It will get the same result as my solution.

Comment: How are you adding the gradient? Are you using a `CAGradientLayer` or are you creating a new image using Core Graphics to draw a gradient over the image in a bitmap?

Comment: @robmayoff I'm using the latter. I've also tried to add a CAGradientLayer to UIImageView but it leaded to the same result.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that you use to create the gradient-ized image.

Comment: @robmayoff Sorry about missing the code. I've updated my question.

Comment: You're passing `NO` for the `opaque` argument of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Do your images have any transparent pixels? If not, try passing `YES` for the `opaque` argument instead.

Comment: @robmayoff It is the point! I didn't notice that parameter...... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A layer whose `contents` is an image with an alpha channel must always be blended with the layers behind it. (iOS assumes that the image has transparency if it has an alpha channel; it doesn't check whether any of the alphas are less than 1.0.)

You're creating gradient-ized images with alpha channels because you're passing `NO` to the `opaque` argument of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Assuming all of your source images are in fact opaque, you can (and should) create opaque gradient-ized images by passing `YES`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
```

Passing `YES` tells UIKit to create a graphics context, and eventually an image, with no alpha channel.